# undefined refernce to

Tags: c++, pointers, c++builder

In the following code

```
map<nsaddr_t, Rating*>::iterator it;
```

generate error for the following line

```
(it->second)->updateRating(alpha, beta, TRUST_FADING, 1);
```

the error of "undefined reference to" during compilation.

Is the syntax correct or needs to anything else.

I didn't find the declaration of second in the whole code.

```
void TrustManager::updateTrust(nsaddr_t address, double alpha, double beta)
{
    map<nsaddr_t, Rating*>::iterator it;
    it = trust_t.find(address);
    if (it == trust_t.end())
    {
        trust_t[address] = initNewRating(alpha, beta, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        (it->second)->updateRating(alpha, beta, TRUST_FADING, 1);
    }
}
bool TrustManager::isTrustworthy(nsaddr_t from)
{
    map<nsaddr_t, Rating*>::iterator it;
    it = trust_t.find(from);
    if (it != trust_t.end())
    {
        double alpha = (it->second)->getAlpha();
        double beta = (it->second)->getBeta();
        double dev = alpha/(alpha+beta);
        return (dev >= UNTRUST_TOLERANCE) ? false:true;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

the full error is

```
In function `TrustManager::updateTrust(int, double, double)':
:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `Rating::updateRating(double, double, double, double)'


In function `TrustManager::handleInactivityTimeout()':

(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `Rating::updateRating(double, double, double, double)'
In function `TrustManager::initNewRating(double, double, double)':

trustmanager.cc:(.text+0x306): undefined reference to `Rating::updateRating(double, double, double, double)'

In function `DSRAgent::DSRAgent()':

(.text+0x5b7): undefined reference to `makeRouteCache()'

In function `RouteCache::pre_noticeRouteUsed(Path const&, Path&, double, ID const&)':

(.text+0x54b): undefined reference to `cache_ignore_hints'

routecache.cc:(.text+0x620): undefined reference to `cache_use_overheard_routes'

dsr/routecache.o: In function `RouteCacheClass::create(int, char const* const*)':

(.text._ZN15RouteCacheClass6createEiPKPKc[RouteCacheClass::create(int, char const* 

const*)]+0x7): undefined reference to `makeRouteCache()'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The Rating is defined as follows:

```
class Rating
{
public:
    Rating() { alpha = 1.0; beta = 1.0;}
    Rating(double a, double b) { alpha = a; beta = b; last_t =
        Scheduler::instance().clock();}
    void updateRating(double a, double b, double fading, double weight);
    inline double getAlpha() { return alpha; }
    inline double getBeta() { return beta; }
    inline Time getTime() { return last_t; }
private:
    //the rating of misbehavior
    double alpha;
    //the rating of good behavior
    double beta;
    //last updated time
    Time last_t;
};
class PackData {
public:
    PackData();
    PackData(Packet* packet, Time t);
    Packet* packet;
    Time t;
};
```

Comment: "undefined reference" is a linker error, not a compiler error. Seems like you forgot to define some function for which you provided a declaration

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: there no member named second in the Rating

Comment: @user2214138 `second` relates to the map iterator, not the object in question. `second` returns the value of the key/value pair the iterator currently points to. In this case, it's a pointer to an object of the class 'Rating'

Comment: We may be able to help you better, if you told us the full definition of the `Rating` class.

Comment: These are not a compiler errors, these are linker errors. You haven't told the linker where all the code is.

Comment: I'm guessing that you've forgotten to compile some files.

Comment: @ATaylor i have posted code for Rating

Comment: Double check, that you've got the exact prototype for `updateRating` in your corresponding C++ file.

Comment: i didn't get u @ATaylor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty precise:

```
In function `TrustManager::updateTrust(int, double, double)':
:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `Rating::updateRating(double, double, double, double)'
```

You are calling the function `updateRating()` from within `updateTrust()`, but you did not define the function anywhere - at least, not where the linker would find it.

The numerous follow-up errors of the same kind hint at a translation unit not properly added to the compiler / linker command line. `updateRating()`, `makeRouteCache()`, `cache_ignore_hints` etc. etc. - all those have to be defined somewhere.

> The Rating is defined as follows:

That is a *declaration* of `updateRating()`, not a *definition*. Note that there is no function body (`{ ... }`) in that header.

(Besides, it is good practice to *not* provide function bodies (or other definitions) in header files, but to keep them in corresponding .cpp files instead. For one thing, it makes the header files easier to read, i.e. somewhat self-documenting.)

Comment: updateRating is defined in the header file that is called in the C++ file under update Trust

Comment: it seems like  (it->second)   this thing is generating errors.

Comment: @user2214138: That is a *declaration*, not a *definition*. You are telling the compiler that there *will be* a function `updateRating()` somewhere (or the compiler would give you an error already), but you don't *define* what that function actually *does*. So the compiler compiles the code without error, expecting the linker to find the definition elsewhere - but it cannot, and thus the "undefined reference" error.